# Is this an early Duplo mini figure?

Tags: duplo, minifigure-identification

Just wondering if you have ever seen this figure before?

[image]

I've had it since I was a kid in the early 80's, and it's always lived with my lego (which was mostly hand-me-downs from my older brother - ie Space #897 rocket set).  It doesn't fit with Lego, but does seem to fit with Duplo.

Looking at early Duplo mini figures, they look vaguely similar, however the Duplo figures are squared off, whereas this figure's body is circular.

There's no markings to indicate brand...

Just a little mystery in my life.  :)

Comment: I've just been scouring eBay... and as noted, the above is "similar" to the early Duplo figures, however when you look at the artwork on the faces... the eyes are completely different, and even the mouth is at an angle that I haven't seen on other Duplo... Has me thinking that this is a toy from something completely different, that just happen to look like it could fit on Duplo...

Comment: My first thought was Fisher-Price Little People, but they typically come with a different underside.

Comment: I saw them too during my search, but they all have a "step" down the body, whereas this is straight.  And yes - the bottom of my piece has 2 concentric rings; the inner ring fits (a little loosely; perhaps from age?) over a Duplo stud.  The outer ring fits quite well "over" 4 studs - the "cut out" sections falling neatly into place...

Answer (score 7):

At last, I have your answer. The figure is from a "Giant Pre-School Loc Bloc" set, likely the "Playground" one shown in the picture.  [image]

Nearly a month later, while doing unrelated research, I found "Giant Brix Blox", a second possible source of these types of figures;

[image]

It makes since given that sources claim Loc Blocs & Brix Blox were both imported from the Japanese company Kawada.

Comment: I don't know how you did it, but well done and welcome to Bricks SE! I spent a good few hours trying to find this figure to no avail. I'm glad someone could finally solve this mystery!

Comment: Persistence. Once my curiosity is piqued I have a hard time letting it go.  Sometimes a blessing, often times a curse ;)

Comment: Well I commend you for that! :)